# convert Unix timestamp to float

Tags: javascript, parsing, floating-point

I have a UNiX timestamp containing date and time (see below). How can I convert that to a float? In the past I used this

```
 var date = Date.parse(a[0]);
 var timestamp = parseFloat(date);
```

but that only works for a date, not for time.

```
06-03-2015T11:00:00Z
03-03-2015T05:00:00Z
03-03-2015T06:00:00Z
03-03-2015T07:00:00Z
03-03-2015T08:00:00Z
03-03-2015T09:00:00Z
```

Comment: `06-03-2015T11:00:00Z` doesn't seem to be an acceptable standard. Try different date format.

Comment: This is what my colleague sent me: 2015-10-12T13:12:51Z <-- this is a the standard Unix Timestamp.

niaz [1:24 PM]
T and Z are two separator in the timestamp. T represents beginning of the time segment whilst Z represents end of the timestamp.

Comment: Standard Unix format is a long based on the unix epoch...

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: That's a standard ISO-8601 timestamp. It has nothing to do with Unix. You'll also notice that the order of the date parts is different in your question and your comment.

Comment: Sorry, He sent me two versions: the first one as shown in the original message, and then the second one where the year is at the end of the date. So it is ISO-8601. How do I convert that to a float? Is that possible somehow?

Comment: So how do I convert this timestamp to a Unix timestamp and then to a floating point number?